# SSH: How to start a process that won't end after system reboot?

Tags: linux, process, ssh, startup

Is there a way to do this so when I reboot my linux server the process will reopen on startup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, you need to add a startup script in `/etc/rc.d/` or `/etc/rc.local`. Thats how all daemons are started. However you need to have root permissions for this.

Since you tagged it as ssh, I guess you don't have root permissions. So you can create a crontab entry that runs a script to launch your process after every reboot:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Add the following line in the file that opens up:

```
@reboot  /path/to/your_script.sh
```

Comment: Good Idea. I will try that. After adding the cron, how would I remove it if needed to.

Comment: Same as before. crontab -e and delete that line from the file

Comment: When trying the command crontab -e it respods "no crontab for (myusername)" How do I make one?

Comment: Strange, it should create one (after complaining) if there isn't any. What version of linux are you on?

Comment: Basic 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2011.09

Comment: Never mind. fixed it the vi editor wasn't saving.

Comment: Now, if I had root access how would I do this?

Comment: You could add a line in /etc/rc.local. That is a script run after everything else is initialized on the system.